# Unity is not changing SQL database value

Tags: c#, php

I got this php on my server, that is called to run when I click on a button to add currency:

```
// Select player_name
$check = mysqli_query($conn,"select Currency from player where Name='$player_name'");
$checkrows=mysqli_num_rows($check);

if($checkrows==1) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO player (Currency) VALUES ('post_player_currency')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die('Error querying database.');
    echo ("DATABASE: Currency added ");
} else { 
// Insert player into database
    echo "DATABASE: Currency NOT added ";
}
?>
```

And on my Unity C# script, I have this:

```
public IEnumerator AddCurrency(Text playername, Text playercurrency) {
    _tempCoins = int.Parse(coins.text);
    _tempCoins += 10;
    coins.text = _tempCoins.ToString();


    WWWForm form = new WWWForm ();
    form.AddField ("post_player_name", playername.text);
    form.AddField ("post_player_currency", playercurrency.text);

    WWW www = new WWW (RegisterPlayerURL, form);
    yield return www;
    print (www.text);

    if (www.text == "DATABASE: Currency added ") {
        print ("TRANSACTION: Current Coins: " + _tempCoins);
    }
}
```

The scripts themselves are *working*, but what I don't understand is why I get **Error querying database.** everytime as result, instead of it actually adding the value to the database.

A very similar script to register a player to the database that I made, is working just fine. I've spent a lot of time and I cannot figure out why this one doesn't work.

Help is appreciated! Thanks!